# Sum of all values in matrix (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix

So I'm trying to create a matlab function that takes two inputs, a matrix and a value, and returns the sum of all values in the matrix except for all instances of the given value. So far this is the code I have written:

```
function [total] = sumAllExcept(matrix, except)
    total = 0;
    for i = 1:size(matrix, 1)
        for k  = 1:size(matrix, 2)
            if(matrix(i, k) ~= except)
                total = total + matrix(i,k);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The error message that I am receiving when trying to run the program is:
" Undefined function 'sumAllExcept' for input arguments of type 'double'. "
I would greatly appreciate it if you would show me whats wrong with this and fix anything that you can.  Thank you!

Comment: So that answer to this problem is a one liner? Just say sum(sum(matrix ~= except)) takes care of everything for me? Sorry about my silly questions. I really don't get matlab compared to other programming languages

Comment: Oh wait! I got that wrong! I thought you were looking for the count! My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum the array after filtering out `except` using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
total = sum(matrix( matrix ~= except ));
```

The result of using the logical index `matrix ~= except` on `matrix` returns a column vector, so only one `sum` is required.

---

The error "`Undefined function 'sumAllExcept' for input arguments of type 'double'.`" is likely due to the function not being on MATLAB's path or the function name `sumAllExcept` not matching the filename (i.e., `sumAllExcept.m`).

Comment: Sorry for the needy request, but would it be possible for you to write out the entire function. I'm still getting the same error messages. Thank you for your much valued time

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "entire function"; that one-line of code can be dropped into your `sumAllExcept` function to replace the loops and `if` statement.  I did add a note on the undefined function error though.

Comment: Thank you TroyHaskin. That all really helped. I have the function working perfectly and you have saved me much time and hair tearing out

Comment: @ScottRothbaum Don't forget to accept the solution by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to it, if it solved your problem.

Comment: No problem. I did that. Thank you for all your help